# Custom domains for preview environments in Azure Static Web Apps?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-static-web-app

On Azure Static Web Apps, you get 10 staging environments with a pro plan, and you can set these up to have [stable URLs per-branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/named-environments?tabs=github-actions).

I've got a few branches like this (eg. `stage`, `dev`, etc.) that I'd like to be subdomains on our default domain. Meaning, builds on branch `stage` would go to `stage.foo.com` and so on. I've added a few of them as custom domains, but these all go to the `main`/production branch. I can't figure out how to point them to the specific staging branch.

I thought one option might be to set the CNAME of the subdomain to the stable branch domain, like:

```
CNAME  stage  foo-stage.1.centralus.azurestaticapps.net
```

But I can't find mention of this anywhere and I worry that it wouldn't validate the domain this way. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue. The documentation does not mention this as an option. I tried adding a CNAME record to a named stable environment. However, this does not work due to HSTS, HTTP Strict Transport Security, being enabled by Azure on the named environment.

Edit: I have created a support ticket with Microsoft. I will update when I get a response

Edit2: Currently it's not possible to use a custom domain for named environments. It is possible to add custom domains to Azure App Services..

I have created a suggestion to get this feature added https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/e255188c-7918-ed11-a81b-6045bd853198

Comment: Thanks for doing that! Did you ever get a response?

Comment: @gbanks I just got a final response today and currently it's not possible. I have created a suggestion to add it in: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/e255188c-7918-ed11-a81b-6045bd853198