# Azure Static Web App with Custom Domain not working with Traffic Splitting

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app, custom-domain

I have an Azure SWA with a Production and Preview environment. I want to A/B test my app by splitting traffic between these two. I have deployed the two versions to each environment. When I browse each, both apps resolve and work as intended.

I then split the traffic with the Traffic Splitting (Preview) feature. After doing so, both app versions continue to resolve and work as intended.

Next, I add a Custom domain to the SWA and go through the external validation process using a CNAME record on my DNS. The validation succeeds and I set my custom domain to be the default.

However, when I browse to the custom domain address, I get a 404. I tried doing so from multiple ISPs, browsers, and secret modes to ensure it was not a caching issue.

When I go back to Traffic Splitting and switch it off, my custom domain resolves correctly.

Does anyone know how to setup Traffic Splitting AND Custom Domains simultaneously?

Comment: It might be because it is not supported.

"Adding a custom domain to a preview environment is not supported." Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain You might also be interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73043727/custom-domains-for-preview-environments-in-azure-static-web-apps